# Is it required to manually run e2fsck at regular intervals?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, ext4, ext3

Is it required to manually run the `e2fsck` (used to check a Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 file system) at regular intervals, an if so, how often should I run it?

Or can I rely on a present S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology) system to report any errors, and then run `e2fsck` in case errors are reported?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Thanks for the comments, which lead to the improvements.  I also read through and appreciate your previous answer referenced in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMART and `e2fsck` check different aspects of your harddisk. 
SMART checks your harddive’s *hardware* (eg spinup time, bad blocks, temperature, working hours, etc.) `e2fsck` checks the integrity of the *contents* of your harddrive.

Let me introduce two more Linux commands here: `fsck` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)) and `tune2fs` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)).

- `fsck` is a generic wrapper around several filesystem specific checkers, such as `e2fsck`.
- `tune2fs` sets different parameters for filesystems, among which the interval and/or frequency for which file systems are checked.

The manual of `tune2fs` is very clear about regularly checking the filesystem:

> It is strongly recommended that either -c (mount-count-dependent) or
>   -i (time-dependent) checking be enabled to force periodic full e2fsck(8) checking of the filesystem. Failure to do so may lead to
>   filesystem corruption (due to bad disks, cables, memory, or kernel
>   bugs) going unnoticed, ultimately resulting in data loss or
>   corruption.

To check the current settings of your filesystem, you can use the following command (edit the device `/dev/sda1` as appropriate):

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | egrep -h 'Maximum mount count|Check interval|Last checked'
```

This will return the two parameters which can be set by the -c and -i parameters of `tune2fs` and the last time the filesystem is checked. To set those parameters to different values, you can use the following command (edit the device `/dev/sda1` as appropriate) to check the filesystem every 8 mounts or once a month (whichever comes first):

```
sudo tune2fs -c 8 -i "1m" /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the manual reference, and I now understand how to read it.

Comment: I edited the answer based on the insights of @KamilMaciorowski; @KamilMaciorowski: thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for the update, and I can see that there are substantial changes for the previous (accepted) answer.  I appreciate your update to the improved revision.